# Image Dataset for Cardiac cells for Mus musculus?

Tags: cell-culture, database, microscopy, imaging, mouse

I'm working on developing a transfer learning model to detect cells in a culture using microscopic images.
for that i require data set of images having microscopic images of various cell types. Is there any such database present? Any open source research work having  microscopic images of cardiac cells that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Sure help yourself with the broad institute image sets collection

Broad Bioimage Benchmark Collection - Annotated biological image sets for testing and validation:
https://data.broadinstitute.org/bbbc/image_sets.html

And the EMBL-EBI:
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/bioimage-archive/

No mouse cardica cells, but I am confident you can easily do transfer learning after training on those.